# ManualResetEvent (from C#) implementation on C++: how to avoid race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'd like to learn more about multithreading programming, and I thought that it would be a good exercise to try to implement some of the C# synchronization primitives in C++.
I've started with [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2), and this is what I have so far:

```
class manual_reset_event
{
public:
    void wait_one()
    {
        if (cv_flag_.load() == false)
        {
            thread_local std::mutex mutex;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            cond_var_.wait(lock, [this]() { return cv_flag_.load(); });
        }
    }

    void set()
    {
        cv_flag_.store(true);
        cond_var_.notify_all();
    }

    void reset()
    {
        cv_flag_.store(false);
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable cond_var_;
    std::atomic<bool> cv_flag_;
};
```

However, there is a race condition here: you could call wait_one() on one thread, pass the if (cv_flag) check, and then call set from another thread. This will cause wait_one() to wait, even though cv_flag_ is now true.
I could solve this by using a lock on wait_one, set and reset.
I think I could also solve this by calling cond_var_.notify_all() immediately after cond_var_.wait() on wait_one(), but I don't think this is a great idea (although maybe I'm wrong).
I was wondering if there is something else (maybe even a completely different approach without using conditional_variables) that I can do here to avoid this race condition.

Comment: Not an expert but have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-entercriticalsection

Comment: `thread_local std::mutex mutex;` have no sense - `thread_local` mean that every thread have own mutex, when mutex must be single for all threads

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it is simplest to just use order to insides of your object with mutexes and ignore atomics. Just make sure that all accesses to your data are protected with a lock.

If you only store a single bit, then it is possible that when doing `set` and `reset` quickly afterwards will lead to lost wakeups as the threads waiting will be scheduled only after `reset` is completed. To resolve the issue I will use a counter. Lowest bit of the counter is its "open" state. Every change of this state is implemented with an increment. I use 64-bit counter just in case. It is extremely unlikely that 32 bits will not be enough, even if it may wrap-around during long-running program.

```
class manual_reset_event
{
public:
    void wait_one()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        uint64_t initial_value = value_;
        if(initial_value & 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        while (value_ == initial_value)
        {
            signalled_.wait(lock);
        }
    }

    void set()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        if((value_ & 1) == 0)
        {
            value_++;
            lock.release(); // optimization
            signalled_.notify_all();
        }
    }

    void reset()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        if(value_ & 1)
        {
            value_++;
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable signalled_;
    uint64_t value_;
};
```

If you are insisting on avoiding unnecessary lock use, you can use atomics, but the solution is somewhat trickier, as there are many more orderings to consider.

```
class manual_reset_event
{
public:
    void wait_one()
    {
        uint64_t initial_value = value_;
        if(initial_value & 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        while (value_ == initial_value)
        { // !
            signalled_.wait(lock);
        }
    }

    void set()
    {
        uint64_t initial_value = value_;
        if(initial_value & 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        // Still need lock to prevent lost wakeup if atomic change happens when
        // other thread is on "// !" line.
        if(value.compare_exchange_strong(initial_value, initial_value + 1)) {
        // One strong attempt is enough. If it fails than someone else must have
        // succeeded. It's as if these two set() operations happened at the same time.
            lock.release();
            signalled_.notify_all();
        }
    }

    void reset()
    {
        uint64_t initial_value = value_;
        if((initial_value & 1) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        value.compare_exchange_strong(initial_value, initial_value + 1);
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable signalled_;
    std::atomic<uint64_t> value_;
};
```

Comment: for example `signalled_.notify_all();` called while you hold `mutex_`, after waiting threads waked - it also try again acquire the same mutex `mutex_` in concurrent. very not the best implementation. common mutex need only for protect shared state of  `manual_reset_event`. but threads after wake must not again acquire/release it

Comment: @RbMm, it seems that your comment might have been cut. Are you suggesting to do `lock.release()` before `signalled_.notify_all()`?

Comment: even if you exit from critical section (release `mutex_`) before call `notify_all()` - this not help. what will be if **several** threads wait for event ? after all it will be notify - exit from wait - all it in concurrent try acquire mutex again. will be bottleneck here. need another implementation at all.

Comment: @RbMm, but this applies to *any* use of `notify_all`. Are you suggesting that this function should not be used?

Comment: i suggested use **separate** `condition_variable` for every thread, in your implementation you wait for **common** `signalled_` and you use **comon** mutex `mutex_` for both - protect state of object and threads wait. i have solution when common mutex used only for protect state of object. no more common data (except `signaled` flag). every thread use self local `condition_variable` and only for implement wait/wake. and dont know *c++* ( i windows only programmer) - are exist another *c++* "api" for wait/wake in os independent manner ? i not found, except `condition_variable` here

Comment: *The notifying thread does not need to hold the lock on the same mutex as the one held by the waiting thread(s); in fact doing so is a pessimization, since the notified thread would immediately block again, waiting for the notifying thread to release the lock.*. in case >1 threads wait for `signalled_.` pessimization much more strong - inside `signalled_.wait(lock)`, after thread already waked - the `mutex_` will be **again**  acquired. which is bad and not need by logic. we just release it in `lock(mutex_);` destructor after this. the `condition_variable` not need here by sense at all..

Comment: ... i [used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52469549/6401656) it only as trick - for wait in os independent manner. really will be good, if exist api like *WaitForAlertByThreadId* and *AlertThreadByThreadId* - for enter to wait state and alert thread by it id. but i not found such in c++ (exist in windows native api)

Comment: I inserted `lock.release()` as a small optimization. Otherwise, I believe it should work fine. Efficient implementation of `condition_variable` will wake threads one at the time.

Comment: this not strong help in case several waiting threads (just waked) and multiple cores. they in practice all at once I will try to seize mutex. sory for question - are in *c++* exit another wait primitives, when thread enter to wait state without any additional object and can be waked by it [*id*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id) ?

Comment: also `lock.release();signalled_.notify_all();` think not correct if threads begin swapped between this 2 calls, and another thread reset event. correct call `signalled_.notify_all();` inside mutex held

Comment: As I said, proper implementation of `std::condition_variable` will avoid thundering herd, by moving threads to another futex or otherwise waking one at the time. In C++ cond-vars are the way to go, there is no action by id and it would be a bad idea. Order is correct, you can't lose a wake-up by moving `notify` forward in time.

Comment: *proper implementation of std::condition_variable* - this is impossible - `wait(lock)` must return control to client code with `mutex` to which point `lock` **owned** . **client** release mutex in `lock` destructor. for ensure this - insert some delay (sleep, messagebox, etc) in the end of `wait_one()` - so when `signalled_.wait(lock);` already return but destructor of `lock` yet not called

Comment: so insert some like `MessageBox` in the end of `wait_one()` - here by design all threads must be set and run. but you will view only **single** messagebox at time. another thread not show self messagebox, until current not close self and free mutex. the client code control this point. implementation of `condition_variable` nothing can do with this

Comment: and just check `lock.release();` need be removed - after it `signalled_.notify_all();` not work

Answer (score 1):

one possible implementation - hold list of waiting for event threads. for protect state of `manual_reset_event` can be used `std::mutex`. when thread begin wait - he check state of event, and if it not signaled - insert self "wait block" in list. this is done inside "critical section" protected by common object mutex. then if we need wait for event (when and only when we insert self to wait list) - begin wait on wait block. but very important exit from "critical section" before this and not even temporary acquire it **after** wait end. from another side, thread which set event - get list of waited threads and then notify all it (after exit from critical section) or possible notify only single, which begin wait first. so with this we can implement manual resent event logic (when all waited threads wake at once) or auto reset event logic - when only single thread will be waked, and event will be just reset again (really not set to signal state at all. only when no more waited threads - event signaled.

```
class manual_reset_event : std::mutex
{
    struct WaitBlock : public std::condition_variable, std::mutex  
    {
        WaitBlock(WaitBlock* next) : next(next), signaled(false) {}

        WaitBlock* next;
        volatile bool signaled;

        void Wait()
        {
            // synchronization point with Wake()
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*this);

            while (!signaled)
            {
                // notify_one() yet not called
                wait(lock);
            }
        }

        void Wake()
        {
            {
                // synchronization point with Wait()
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*this);
                signaled = true;
            }
            notify_one();
        }
    };

    WaitBlock* _head;
    volatile bool _signaled;

public:

    manual_reset_event(bool signaled = false) : _signaled(signaled), _head(0) { }

    void wait()
    {
        lock();//++ protect object state

        WaitBlock wb(_head);

        bool inserted = false;

        if (!_signaled)
        {
            _head = &wb;
            inserted = true;
        }

        unlock();//-- protect object state

        if (inserted)
        {
            wb.Wait();
        }
    }

    // manual reset logic
    void set_all() 
    {
        WaitBlock* last, *head = 0;

        lock();//++ protect object state
        head = _head, _signaled = true;
        unlock();//-- protect object state

        while (last = head)
        {
            head = head->next;
            last->Wake();
        }
    }

    // auto reset logic - only one thread will be signaled, event auto reset
    void set_single()  
    {
        WaitBlock* last = 0;

        lock();//++ protect object state

        if (!_signaled)
        {
            if (last = _head)
            {
                // wake first waiting thread

                WaitBlock* prev = 0, *pwb;

                while (pwb = last->next)
                {
                    prev = last, last = pwb;
                }

                (prev ? prev->next : _head) = 0;

            }
            else
            {
                // nobody wait
                _signaled = true;
            }
        }
        unlock();//-- protect object state

        if (last)
        {
            last->Wake();
        }
    }

    void reset()
    {
        _signaled = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not safe. If a thread is preempted just before `wait(lock)` and other one calls `Wake` at this time then its wake-up will be lost.

Comment: `notify_one()` will be called before `wait(lock)`. `notify_one` would not awake nothing and a `Wait` thread would go to sleep forever. `mutex` is irrelevant, since it's only used by one thread.

Comment: @zch - yes, view now. because initially i use another implementation of wait/wake, where order not play role

Comment: @zch - i fix implementation, by correct usage local mutex (on waitblock). now or `Wake` first set `signaled = true;` and another thread will be not wait at all, or if it will begin wait - this will be before `signaled = true;` and as result before `notify_one();` call. thx for view bug

Comment: @zch - let thread `A` call `Wait`, thread `B` call `Wake`. here common mutex acquire both `A` and `B`. if `A` before `B` acquire `mutex` - `B` call `notify_one();` after `wait` in `A` (call begin inside mutex held). if `B` acquire mutex before `A` - `signaled` will be set to true and visible for `A` when it acquire mutex and it not begin wait at all. and here `notify_one();` called already ouside mutex, so not conflict with `A` acquire it on exit from `wait`